# Minimization Nminimize nnum error

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I have imported data (mat is the name, 1x100 dimensional vector)and written a likelihood function for normal distribution.

```
f[miu_, sigma_] := -1/2 Log[2 Pi sigma] - (mat - miu)^2/(2 sigma^2)
Minimize[{Total[f[miu, sigma]] && miu ≥ 1 && sigma ≥ 1}, {miu, sigma}]
```

However this gives me error

```
NMinimize::nnum: Function value False at{miu, sigma} = {-0.936293, 0.280416}is not a number
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: If this error occurs with a shorter vector, please provide it, so that readers can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You are giving a Boolean expression in the place of an objective function. The error message kind of makes that clear..

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 6], 200];
f[miu_, sigma_] := -1/2 Log[2 Pi sigma] - (mat - miu)^2/(2 sigma^2) // N // Total;
NMaximize[{f[miu, sigma], 1 <= miu <= 5 && 1 <= sigma <= 5}, 
           {miu, sigma}, Method -> "NelderMead"]

(* {-502.338, {miu -> 2.01306, sigma -> 5.}} *)
```